# Accumulo delete row with security label

Tags: java, accumulo

I'm trying to delete an Accumulo row on a table. The table looks like this:

```
Key: id0001 hero:alias [secretId] 1525804166026 false             Value: Batman
Key: id0001 hero:name [secretId] 1525804166026 false              Value: Bruce Wayne
Key: id0001 hero:wearsCape? [secretId] 1525804166026 false        Value: true
Key: id0002 hero:alias [] 1525804166026 false                     Value: Robin
Key: id0002 hero:name [secretId] 1525804166026 false              Value: Dick Grayson
Key: id0002 hero:wearsCape? [secretId] 1525804166026 false        Value: true
Key: id0003 hero:alias [] 1525804166026 false                     Value: Joker
Key: id0003 hero:name [] 1525804166026 false                      Value: Unknown
Key: id0003 hero:wearsCape? [] 1525804166026 false                Value: false
```

I'm trying to delete row with ID "id0001", ColFam "hero", ColQual "name". My code is like this:

```
    Mutation mut = new Mutation("id0001");
    mut.putDelete(new Text("hero"), new Text("name"));
    try (Scanner scanner1 = commishConn.createScanner("GothamPD", new Authorizations("secretId"))) {
      //scanner1.setRange(Range.exact("id0001"));
      for (Entry<Key,Value> entry : scanner1) {
        mut.putDelete(entry.getKey().getColumnFamily(), entry.getKey().getColumnQualifier());
      }
    }
    BatchWriter batchwriter = conn.createBatchWriter("GothamPD",1000000, 60000, 2);
    batchwriter.addMutation(mut);
    batchwriter.flush();
```

It's not deleting even though, I have specified the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

The `ColumnVisibility` is part of the column. You need to include it if you are going to delete an entry with a non-empty visibility.

The `Mutation.putDelete` method [has a variation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.9.0/org/apache/accumulo/core/data/Mutation.html#putDelete-org.apache.hadoop.io.Text-org.apache.hadoop.io.Text-org.apache.accumulo.core.security.ColumnVisibility-) which accepts a third parameter for the `ColumnVisibility`.

For example, replace:

```
  for (Entry<Key,Value> entry : scanner1) {
    mut.putDelete(entry.getKey().getColumnFamily(), entry.getKey().getColumnQualifier());
  }
```

with the following:

```
  for (Entry<Key,Value> entry : scanner1) {
    Key k = entry.getKey();
    mut.putDelete(k.getColumnFamily(), k.getColumnQualifier(), k.getColumnVisibilityParsed());
  }
```

WARNING: Be careful with this; this scan-and-delete loop will delete all data found by the scanner.

Note: the `putDelete` before your scanner loop is redundant; it would already be deleted, if it exists, in the loop.